# Show menu on page with all sub-pages and sub-sub-pages of that page

Tags: sub-menu, wp-list-pages

I am trying to create a menu, with sub-pages and sub-sub-pages of a current page.

I want the menu to work as a dropdown, where the sub-sub-pages for a sub-pages are shown when the user clicks the sub-page, and hidden again if the user clicks on the sub-page a second time. So it is important that the sub-pages in the menu are not links.

I need to show the same menu, no matter how deep in the sub pages the user is at.

Can anyone help? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`get_page_children`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_children) function to retrieve all sub pages

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'page', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
$children = get_page_children( get_the_ID(), $the_query->query() );

if ( !empty( $children ) ) {
    foreach ( $children as $child ) {
        // render menu
    }
}
```